# Cakephp: inner join with edit from component

Tags: cakephp

I'm still in the learning process of Cakephp, so excuse me if my question is in a way ... 'odd'.

What I want to achieve:
With an inner join retreive te ID's of clients linked in the assignments table. The problem is the ID's in the assignments table are hashed. 
I thought the best way is to make a component with the has and than call it in the sql condition like this: **$this->IdHash->unmake_hash('AssignmentInfo.client_ID')**

It is not working and I get this error: **Error: syntax error, unexpected 'AssignmentInfo' (T_STRING), expecting ')'**

How can I solve this problem in a good way?

```
<?php
class AdminsController extends AppController{
var $name = 'Admins';
    public $components = array('IdHash');


public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('AssignmentInfo');
    $this->set('ClientAssignmentList', $this->AssignmentInfo->find('all'
        , array(
            'joins' => array(
                array(
                    'table' => 'archief_client',
                    'alias' => 'client',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'client.id = $this->IdHash->unmake_hash('AssignmentInfo.client_ID')'
                    )
                )
            ),
            array(
                'order' => 'AssignmentInfo.ID DESC'
            ))));
```

}
}

?>

Comment: You cannot use Cakephp code within SQL. Your `conditions` array is the text that goes in SQL's `WHERE` clause. Does your data model, have a archief_client table with an autoincrement primary key and in the table behind the AssignmentInfo model you store a hashed version of that primary key?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The archief_client has an autoincrement primary key that corresponds with a hashed client_ID key in the Assignment table.

Comment: Can you change your data model to store the unhashed value. IMHO: You are asking for future difficulties because you have intentionally bypassed the advantages a SQL database has to offer (e.g., foreign key constraints, indexes, the ability to write efficient SQL code.) Even if you are not allowed to change the AssignmentInfo table, I would create an intermediate table with two columns: `client_id` & `hashed_client_id`. This way you can JOIN without using PHP application code.

Comment: You are absolutely right. For me this means I have to change important features to my DB and code, but at the end this wil be a much better way of programming and to handle my project in the future. You just reminded me that I should use proper code and not fix it all using PHP. Tnx!